# simple select is taking huge time on the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I have a table with around 17 millions of Transaction data. It have clustered key and Non Clustered key on Key columns. To simple select also it is taking 11 minutes to retrieve data and for DML Operations it is taking good amount of time.

Simple select

```
Select * from TransactionTable
```

People will ask what you have done from your side

1)I have created indexes (Clustered and Non Clustered)

2)using DM Views physical stats I have checked whether the table is fragmented or not ?

3)Before doing DML Operations I have Re-Organized the Indexes.

Please suggest me the way

Comment: Are you selecting all 17 million with a *?

Comment: You've forgot to mention query itself. If it is `select * from table` then no idexes will help you at all since you're selecting huge amount of data.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev simple select nothing more that that just retrieving data

Comment: @artm yes I'm selecting

Comment: @mohan111 You're selecting all the data from huge table. No indexes will help you in this case. There is nothing to optimize here.

Comment: but why the table is taking huge time for simple operations also @AndyKorneyev

Comment: @mohan111 because you're requesting huge amount of data from server, thus server has to read the data from disk, transfer to you via network and so on.

Comment: Try if `select top 1000 * from TransactionTable` runs faster.

Comment: any suggestions by experts @AndyKorneyev

Comment: my table is not even opening some times @LukStorms

Comment: @mohan111  The `select *` query you are using will return 17mm records, which will take a long time to be read off the server and transferred over your network.  try selecting a subset of the info with a `top 10` or `where <column> = <value>`.

Comment: it is not the case of selecting top 10 or where condition any way I do when it required. But any way to do partioning or Separate files or Cleaning table @iamdave

Comment: @mohan111  For what purpose?

Comment: @iamdave this table I'm using in lot of procedures and it is giving nightmares

Comment: "I'm using in lot of procedures and it is giving nightmares".  Can you provide one these queries instead?  Your production code is more meaningful and important than any `SELECT *`.  As it stands there isn't much information, in your question, to work with.

Comment: if this table is fine most of the executions will get reduced @destination-data

Comment: @mohan111  That is just fundamentally not how SQL Server works.  The individual query and the indexes it use are what affect the performance.  You absolutely cannot judge performance using a `select * from table`.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think to try to reduce the size of the table by adjusting the data types to the minimum requirements. If you have a lot of Null values, try to use Sparse columns.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: e.g Don't use a bigint where an int is sufficent, or unicode types if you are not holding unicode text and keep data lengths to the minimum requirement. If there are columns with a great deal of Nulls, set Sparse to True in the column properties. It will reduce the overall size of the table.

Answer (score 0):

What might help you, is keeping the data compressed.
If I remember correctly, you'll have to repopulate the table.
The more interesting thing however, is what are you going to do with the data.

Comment: can you tell me the exact usage of compression

Comment: @mohan111. Forget about databases and you tell me please what is compession used for.

Comment: I know the meaning of compression but Data compression in this scenario

Comment: @mohan, as always, reduce IO, pay with CPU.